# Unable to Add Text in my RN Skia Web Project using Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, skia

**I am getting the following error when adding text to my RN Skia Web project which uses Expo Router:**

```
Uncaught Error
_Image.default.resolveAssetSource is not a function
```

**Here is my setup:**

```
//text setup:
const fontSize = 32;
const font = useFont(require('../fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf'), fontSize);

...

   <Text
      x={100}
      y={100}
      text={"test"}
      font={font}
      size={32}
      opacity={100}
    />
```

**Expo Snack:**
**https://snack.expo.dev/@frussohd/skia-web-text-issue**

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. npx create-expo-app@latest -e with-router
2. skipped yarn add @shopify/react-native-skia or npm install @shopify/react-native-skia
3. expo install @shopify/react-native-skia
4. yarn setup-skia-web
5. npm install copy-webpack-plugin --save-dev
6. npm i node-polyfill-webpack-plugin
7. setup webpack.config.js as outlined in [Skia Web Documentation](https://shopify.github.io/react-native-skia/docs/getting-started/web#manual-webpack-installation)
8. yarn add react-native-level-fs
9. yarn add path-browserify
10. added "fs": "react-native-level-fs", "path": "path-browserify", to my dependencies in package.json
11. added skia to my index.js using code splitting
12. yarn add path-browserify again
13. got this Uncaught Error:

> Aborted(CompileError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): expected magic word
> 00 61 73 6d, found 3c 21 44 4f @+0). Build with -sASSERTIONS for more
> info.

13. used [CDN](https://shopify.github.io/react-native-skia/docs/getting-started/web#using-a-cdn)
14. and add a Text object

**GitHub Repo:**
https://github.com/rarepython21/Skia-Text-Bug-w-Expo-Router

Comment: Have you tried to directly load the font: `font={require('../fonts/Roboto-Light.ttf')}`

Comment: Yes, I tried that.